# Save an environment variable without using /bin/bash

Tags: c, linux, bash, variables, environment-variables

I have a program that creates a environment variable called `$EGG` with this code

```
 memcpy(buff,"EGG=",4);
 putenv(buff); 
 system("/bin/bash");
```

And the value of `buff` is used to create an environment variable, and I use it through `$EGG` variable, but for use it I see that I must use the call `system("/bin/bash");`. Otherwise, if I don't use /bin/bash call I don't find my `$EGG` variable.

Is there a way to save my environment variable without calling `/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot modify an existing environment the way you try.

Background: The program you use to create the environment variable `EGG` in gets its own environment on start-up (typically as copy of the environment of the process that starts the program). Inside the program's very own environment `EGG` is created.

When a program ends its environment is also gone and with it would had been created in there.

To modify an environment programmatically do not write a (C) program but use a script.

Using bash this could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export EGG=4
```

save this as for example `set_egg_to_4.sh` and adjust the files mode do be able to execute the it:

```
$ chmod +x set_egg_to_4.sh
```

Then run the script:

```
$ ./set_egg_to_4.sh
```

and test for `EGG`, by doing

```
$ echo $EGG
4
```

Comment: If i want to save permanently my environment variable with c programm. How can i do it?

Comment: You can't. @Alex You can only for the live time of the program and all it's children, like the `bash` you spawned off in your example. This is a conceptual issue.

Comment: A process's environment is inherited from its parent as a copy. A process can only change its own environment.

Answer (score 0):

To "permanently" set an environment variable, add it to your `.bash_profile` file.

```
export EGG=4
```

This file is sourced each time you start a login session, so that `EGG` is added to your environment each time. Any that inherit (directly or indirectly) from this shell will also have `EGG` in its environment.

There may be other files on your system that are sourced immediately on startup, so that a variable set in such a file is available to all processes (regardless of the user). (One I'm think of is `/etc/environment`.)